# Copying contents from a document into a new one with the same format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Right now I have a document that's almost like a template that has bold, indention, header and I would like to be able to take the contents of that document and replace certain strings with what the user inputs in forms that I have set up. I have it working where it makes a new one and replaces the words with just a plain text document with no special formatting. Is there a way to do this with keeping all of the formatting? Anyway it needs to be done is cool, but I've been using mostly PHP and the code I have so far to do it is PHP.

Here's what the code looks like that works with no formatting.

```
<?php  
session_start();


$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'TMP_');

file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents("freewillben1.docx"));

  //replaces string in document with data 
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$placeholders = array('Fff', 'Mmm','Lll');
$namevals = 
array($_SESSION["fName"],$_SESSION["mInitial"],$_SESSION["lName"]);
$path_to_file = 'freewillben1.docx';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace($placeholders,$namevals,$file_contents);
file_put_contents($file,$file_contents);
fclose($fh);


if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file);
// Get a date and timestamp
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$time = time();
// Send file headers
header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourwill.docx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
// Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output data to demonstrate what is not working?

Comment: what you really should do is use a real templating system like [mustache](https://learnwebtutorials.com/tutorial-getting-started-mustache-template-php) to generate your file, then save it however you need

Comment: Are you asking how to read, edit, and save a Microsoft Word document? That's kind of a tall order.

Comment: I was thinking I would have to use some sort of thing like mustache or PHPword but I was just wondering if there was anyway to do it without that. I just want to replace certain placeholder strings in a document and be able to keep the formatting.